# Common strategy to log thread status

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

I have a thread which keeps popping from a queue and it sleeps and writes "queue is empty, sleep for 500ms" into log file if the queue is empty. So if my service has been running for long time, the log will be :
queue is empty, sleep for 500ms
queue is empty, sleep for 500ms
queue is empty, sleep for 500ms
...
...
...

What is the common strategy to avoid this? Obviously i can set a boolean to check if "queue is empty, sleep" has already been logged but it doesn't seem to be an optimal solution. There must be some pattern or strategy to deal with this. Hope you understand I know my question and my question sounds a little stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Stop needlessly and avoidably polling the queue.  Use wait/notify.  Get rid of the deadbeat latency and CPU waste.